# Ruby : Getting error []': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class LineAnalyzer
    @@highest_wf_count = 0
    @@highest_wf_words = Hash.new(0)

    def initialize(content, line_number)
      @content = content
      @line_number = line_number
      calculate_word_frequency(content)
    end

    def calculate_word_frequency(content)
        content.split.each do |word|
          @@highest_wf_words[word.downcase] +=1
        end
        @@highest_wf_words = @@highest_wf_words.sort_by{|k,v| -v}
    end
end 

class Solution

    def initialize()
        @analyzers = Array.new
        @highest_count_words_across_lines = Array.new
    end
    def analyze_file()
        @line_number = 0
        File.foreach('test.txt') do |content|
          @line_number += 1
          @line = LineAnalyzer.new(content,@line_number)
          @analyzers.<<(@line)
        end
    end    
end
```

When trying to create LineAnalyzer object and passing values, getting this error in:

```
@line = LineAnalyzer.new(content,@line_number)
```

This is what I getting:

```
Max-Word-Freq/module2_assignment.rb:34:in `calculate_word_frequency'
    from D:/graded-assignments/course01/module02/assignment-Calc-Max-Word-Freq/module2_assignment.rb:25:in `initialize'
    from D:/graded-assignments/course01/module02/assignment-Calc-Max-Word-Freq/module2_assignment.rb:68:in `new'
    from D:/graded-assignments/course01/module02/assignment-Calc-Max-Word-Freq/module2_assignment.rb:68:in `block in analyze_file'
    from D:/graded-assignments/course01/module02/assignment-Calc-Max-Word-Freq/module2_assignment.rb:66:in `foreach'
    from D:/graded-assignments/course01/module02/assignment-Calc-Max-Word-Freq/module2_assignment.rb:66:in `analyze_file'
    from D:/graded-assignments/course01/module02/assignment-Calc-Max-Word-Freq/solution.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You try to index an array somewhere with a string. Looks like in `calculate_word_frequency`.

Comment: can you please paste the log

Comment: edit the question please instead of adding additional info in comments

Comment: Could you point us to the exact error line?

Comment: What's the value of `content`? Which line is in **#34**? Provide some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this error because you are trying to use an `Array` like a `Hash`.
On this line :

```
 @@highest_wf_words = @@highest_wf_words.sort_by{|k,v| -v}
```

In the first time `@@highest_wf_words` is indeed a `Hash` but the `sort_by` method is returning an `Array`. So when you use it again you have an error.

If you want to sort your hash by value you can do this :

```
@@highest_wf_words = Hash[@@highest_wf_words.sort]
# Or reverse it
@@highest_wf_words = Hash[@@highest_wf_words.sort.reverse]
```

Look at this for further explanation : [Hash::[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D)